# Bundling package.json dependencies for production via grunt

Tags: gruntjs, bundle, libraries, production

I have a project where:

- no require / requirejs is used in any files
- grunt is used as a task runner
- I have devDependencies in package.json and dependencies for web app
  in bower.json
- I use
  [grunt-bower-concat](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat)
  to bundle all dependencies from bower.json and use `<script src=bundle.js></script>` in main html file

I basically want do remove bower from my project and bundle all dependencies from package.js (with its dependencies e.g. moment-timezone requires moment, so both should be in bundle) automatically. Same thing as [grunt-bower-concat](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat) does, but for package.json (ignoring devDependencies ofcourse). I can't use webpack for now. Is there good way to do this? I can't find any grunt plugin for it, and I think for a reason I don't understand.

I know there is grunt-concat but it does not concat dependencies of dependencies automatically (e.g. moment-timezone requires moment, and I don't want to search for what moment-timezone requires and manually add path to this required file).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to bundle your dependencies via grunt. I recommend using [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) as a bundler. It's super fast, and I think it's just what you're looking for.
Simply create a configuration where you paste the dependencies names from your `package.json`, and feed it to browserify like this:

```
browserify: {
   dependencies: {
      src: gruntConfig.jsDependencies,
      dest: 'yourFolder/bundle.js'
   }
}
```

You can also just feed it an array if you prefer: `['moment-timezone', ...]`.